# vue-test-utils window scroll

Tags: vue.js, vue-test-utils

Need some advice on how to test a window scroll event using vue-test-utils
Below is my js

```js
export default {
  created () {
      window.addEventListener('scroll', this.bannerResize);
  },
  methods: {
    topBResize () {
      var header = document.getElementById('topB');
      var pos1 = header.offsetTop;
      var pageYOffset = window.pageYOffset;
      if (pageYOffset > pos1) {
        header.classList.add('sticky');
      } else {
        header.classList.remove('sticky');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Below is my unit test using vue-test-utils

```js
import {expect} from 'chai';
import {createLocalVue, shallow} from 'vue-test-utils'

const localVue = createLocalVue()
localVue.use(VueRouter)
localVue.use(Vuex)

const wrapper = shallow(Banner, {
  localVue,
  router,
  attachToDocument: true
})

describe('topB.vue', () => {
  it('topB resize', () => {
    wrapper.setData({ bsize: true })
    const dBanner = wrapper.find('#topB')
    wrapper.trigger('scroll')
    const pageYOffset = 500;
    const pos1 = 200;
    expect(dBanner.classes()).contains('sticky')
  })
})
```

The test fails when you check if the sticky class is added.

How do I test this method ? I would like to see the sticky class added when window scrolls vertically

Thanks,
RD

Answer (score 3):

You're triggering a `scroll` event on the `div#topB` wrapper, but the event listener is on `window`. JSDom, used by Mocha and Jest, doesn't support the normal JavaScript methods of scrolling `window` via [`window.scrollTo`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo)/[`window.scroll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scroll), but assuming you mount the test instance with [`attachToDocument`](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/options.html#attachtodocument), you can still manually dispatch a `scroll` event with:

```
window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('scroll', { detail: 2000 }))
```

Your event handler would have to parse the event detail for this value and fallback to `window.pageYOffset`.

```
// var pageYOffset = window.pageYOffset;
var pageYOffset = !Number.isNaN(e.detail) ? e.detail : window.pageYOffset;
```

[see GitHub repro 1](https://github.com/tony19-sandbox/vue-test-utils-window-scroll/commit/43524f877f30f00916004de31a08c02adfd9783a)

Alternatively, you can assume the `scroll`-event handler would be called upon scrolling; and test by running the `scroll`-event handler (`wrapper.vm.topBResize()`) directly, and then checking for the expected outcome. You can set `window.pageYOffset` before running the handler:

```
window.pageYOffset = 1000;
wrapper.vm.topBResize();
expect(dBanner.classes()).contains('sticky');
wrapper.pageYOffset = 0;
```

[see GitHub repro 2](https://github.com/tony19-sandbox/vue-test-utils-window-scroll/commit/5766f4cc0c13d4842559bc053f6d17840af1952e)

Comment: Thanks Tony. How do I pass values to the local variables pageYOffset  and pos1 because they are compared in the if clause.

Comment: @RJD It turns out you can actually dispatch a `scroll` event to trigger the handler (see updated answer). On the other hand, you can still take the alternative approach of invoking the scroll handler directly. You can set `window.pageYOffset` beforehand to setup your test, and restore it in a teardown.

Comment: Thanks Tony. I tried calling the wrapper.vm.topBResize() directly and I see the if path not taken message and so the sticky class does not get applied and the test fails

Comment: Did you set `window.pageYOffset` before calling `wrapper.vm.topBResize()`? Also make sure the `attachToDocument` mounting option is `true`.

Comment: Yes I did ...below is the code `import {expect} from 'chai';
import {createLocalVue, mount, shallow} from 'vue-test-utils'

const localVue = createLocalVue()
localVue.use(VueRouter)
const wrapper = shallow(Banner, {
  localVue,
  router,
  attachToDocument: true
})
localVue.use(Vuex)
describe('topB.vue', () => {
    it('topB resize', () => {
    wrapper.setData({ bsize: true })
    const dBanner = wrapper.find('#topB')
    window.pageYOffset = 1000;
 wrapper.vm.bannerResize()
 console.log(dBanner.classes())
    expect(dBanner.classes()).contains('sticky')
  })
})`